# Piping to LogParser

Tags: powershell, pipeline, logparser

I'm working on a set of scripts to manage some logparsing tasks I need to perform on very lard IIS logs that are gzipped.  While working on it, I running into a problem with piping to `logparser`. I simplified my problem to the following.

If I run this, it works as expected.  The log file is not that large and it returns pretty quickly.

```
$query = "Select s-computername, Count(*) as count FROM stdin GROUP by s-computername"
Get-Content .\01-01-16\ex160101.log |
  LogParser "$query" -i:IISW3C -o:CSV -headers:ON -fileMode:1 -q:ON
```

However if I want to put the `LogParser` portion into a PowerShell function to simplify the running of this.  In fact, I really would like to pass in the query, but I'm trying to work backwards from the simplest thing I can think of.

Here's what I wound up with.

```
Function Test-IISLog {
  Begin {
    $query = "Select s-computername, Count(*) as count FROM stdin GROUP by s-computername"
  }
  Process {
    $_ | LogParser "$query" -i:IISW3C -o:CSV -headers:ON -fileMode:1 -q:ON | Write-Output
  }
}
Get-Content .\01-01-16\ex160101.log | Test-IISLog
```

When I run this it just spins it's wheels for a very long time.  I tried different combinations of this command one without the `$_` and one with out the `Write-Output`.  None seem to work. I'm not sure why it's taking so long to return.

Can anyone help with this?  Should I be doing this another way?

My ultimate goal is to have a simple way to run a `logparser` query on a set of IIS logs that have been gzipped and stored in a netapp device.  So far I have the ungzipping portion working well with pipes and as long as I pipe directly to LogParser, it works.  It's when I call `LogParser` from within another PowerShell function that I'm having issues.

Comment: Replace `$_` with `$input`

Comment: $input gave the same results as $_

Answer (score 1):

While it's correct that in a pipeline context the automatic variable `$_` represents the current object, in your case you need a different automatic variable (`$input`, as suggested by Mathias), because you need to handle the function input, even though it comes from a pipeline:

```
function Test-IISLog {
  End {
    $query = "SELECT s-computername, Count(*) AS count FROM stdin GROUP BY s-computername"
    $input | LogParser "$query" -i:IISW3C -o:CSV -headers:ON -fileMode:1 -q:ON
  }
}
```

Quoting from the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx):

> **`$Input`**
>   Contains an enumerator that enumerates all input that is passed to a function. The `$input` variable is available only to functions and script blocks (which are unnamed functions). In the `Process` block of a function, the `$input` variable enumerates the object that is currently in the pipeline. When the `Process` block  completes, there are no objects left in the pipeline, so the `$input` variable enumerates an empty collection. If the function does not have a `Process` block, then in the `End` block, the `$input` variable enumerates the collection of all input to the function.

You could also give the function an actual parameter and use that instead of the automatic variable, but then you'd have to collect the lines in an array yourself:

```
function Test-IISLog {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param(
    [Parameter(
      Mandatory=$true,
      Position=0,
      ValueFromPipeline=$true,
      ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true
    )]
    [string[]]$LogLine
  )

  Begin {
    $query = "SELECT s-computername, Count(*) AS count FROM stdin GROUP BY s-computername"
    $lines = @()
  }
  Process {
    $lines += $LogLine
  }
  End {
    $lines | LogParser "$query" -i:IISW3C -o:CSV -headers:ON -fileMode:1 -q:ON
  }
}
```

However, why go to all this trouble in the first place? `logparser` can read files by itself:

```
$filename = 'C:\path\to\ex160101.log'

$query = @"
SELECT s-computername, Count(*) AS count
FROM '$filename'
GROUP BY s-computername
"@

& logparser.exe $query -i:IISW3C -o:CSV -headers:ON -fileMode:1 -q:ON
```

If anything I'd pass the filename into the function:

```
function Test-IISLog {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param(
    [Parameter(
      Mandatory=$true,
      Position=0,
      ValueFromPipeline=$true,
      ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true
    )]
    [ValidateScript({Test-Path -LiteralPath $_})]
    [string]$Filename
  )

  Process {
    $query = @"
SELECT s-computername, Count(*) AS count
FROM '$filename'
GROUP BY s-computername
"@
    & logparser.exe $query -i:IISW3C -o:CSV -headers:ON -fileMode:1 -q:ON
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll try your example and let you know how it works out.  The reason for not having log parser read the file is because my use case has a bunch of files that are gzipped that I need to feed to log parser as one.  My example above is a simplified version because regardless of the gzipped portion, I could not get this portion to work.

Comment: I tried both examples.  One using $input and the other with the @LogLine.  Both gave similar results to using $_.

Comment: My mistake. You need to process `$input` in total in an `End` block, otherwise each log line would be processed individually by different `logparser` processes. Which, of course, would be utterly pointless.